# when use incorrect password and username system not work properly

Tags: php, html

I have created simple login form in php. There are two pages called `login.html` and `login.php`.`login.html` action page is `login.php`.admin has fixed username and password.when admin uses his password system should redirect to admin page.when user uses his password or username system should redirect to `order.php` page.

when user uses correct password and username system works properly. But problem is, when anyone use incorrect password or username system redirect to `admin.php` page. How can i fix this.i mentioned my php code below.

```
<?php

session_start();

$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="mid";

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    $sql="select * from reg where uname='$uname' and pwd='$pwd'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0){
        header('Location:order.php');
    }
    elseif($uname="Admin" && $pwd="abc123"){
        header('Location:admin.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "incorrect";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elseif condition doesn't check for equality using double equals (==) rather it uses the assignment operator (=) change the condition to

```
 elseif($uname == "Admin" && $pwd == "abc123")
```

Comment: And there is a space between `elseif`... It should be `else if`

Comment: @shahsani refer here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Oops I forgot it. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

Look for what comparison operator you have used

Shouldn't it be '==' or '===' instead of '=' in elseif condition

By using '=' operator you are assigning value to variables and as assignment is successful it returns true which causes redirection to admin.php page

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. The comparison operator is used incorrectly as an assignment operator. Use a `==` for comparison.

The code is corrected as below:

```
if($count > 0){
   header('Location:order.php');
}
else if($uname == "Admin" && $pwd == "abc123"){
   header('Location:admin.php');
}
else{
   echo "incorrect";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change :

```
else{
echo "incorrect";
}
```

to

```
else{
header('Location:login.html');
}
```

or if you want get JS alert

```
else{
die('<script>alert('incorrect');location.href='login.html';</script>');
}
```